# How to send CMake variables to vcpkg dependencies

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I need to send a cmake variable to one the dependcies in vcpkg, more specifically, lets say this is my **vcpkg.json**:

```
{
  "name": "your-project-name",
  "version-string": "1.1.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "vtk"
  ]
}
```

Now I need to set the **VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtQuick** to YES, normally you can do that directlt when you configure your CMake with

```
-DVTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtQuick=YES
```

, but how can I do that in vcpkg? regards.

I have tried the following in my CMake:

```
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
        set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE PATH "toolchain file")
        set(VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtQuick YES CACHE)
endif()
```

But seems like CMake will ignore it,

Answer (score 0):

the vtk port in vcpkg has features so doing:

```
{
  "name": "your-project-name",
  "version-string": "1.1.0",
  "dependencies": [
    { 
        "name": "vtk",
        "features": ["qt"],
        "default-features": false
    }
  ]
}
```

should give you partly what you want already however the Quick module is not included in that feature so you need to go a bit deeper. There are two ways to achieve what you want: a) a ports overlay (which copies the port and edits the `portfile.cmake` to have said option) or b) a triplet overlay using per port customization and setting

```
if(PORT STREQUAL "vtk")
  set(VCPKG_CMAKE_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS -DVTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtQuick=Yes)
endif()
```

Setting `-DVTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GUISupportQtQuick=Yes` in your `CMakeLists.txt` however does nothing since that is completely isolated from what vcpkg does internally.

Comment: (you could also request that a feature qtquick is added to the vtk port so that you don't have to use an overlay or make that PR yourself ;) )

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the *title*, 'How to send CMake variables to vcpkg dependencies': use [`VCPKG_ENV_PASSTHROUGH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/triplets#vcpkg_env_passthrough).

vcpkg uses CMake, but every dependency is built in a sandboxed and sanitised environment. Even dependencies that use CMake are configured, built, and installed independent of the parent project. vcpkg launches a *new* CMake instance, so *CMake* variables in your project cannot be propagated to dependencies, but *environment* variables can, ergo the above mechanism.